# R package installation which is removed from CRAN

Tags: r

I need to install RODBCext package, but this package is removed from cran. So I downloaded the package locally from its archive folder.
I tried to install using the below command

**install.packages("RODBCext.tar.gz",REPOS=NULL, type="SOURCE")**

but the installations is throwing an error

**"r installation of package had non-zero exit status"**

**how to avoid this issue and install the package?**

Comment: I think there's a typo in your command, because packages usually have `tar.gz` extension and not `tat.gz`.

Comment: i have updated it, typo was here not during execution.

Comment: There should be more in the error message, is that all that was shown?

Comment: What OS are you using? Do you have `Rtools` installed (if Windows)?

Answer (score 1):

The easier way to install your package is install from github:

```
pacman::p_load(devtools)
devtools::install_github('zozlak/RODBCext')
library(RODBCext)
```

Here is code. Try this ;)